# Alignment of matrices with annotations on the right side

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, matrices, arrays, gauss

I have a problem with aligning matrices with annotations on the right side. I need the annotations to show the operations I used.

To show the operations I first used the gauss package. Unfortunately the matrices do not look very good. After a couple hours of trying to fix it I found the nicematrix package, which I guess can supply the right alignment.

For both codes and examples please see below.

**Questions:**

1. When using the nicematrix package, how can I insert an arrow like in the first matrix developed with gauss package?
2. The nicematrix package has an option called "columnns-width" which you can use e. g. in a NiceMatrixBlock. When I try to translate the code I get an error saying that *"NiceMatrixBlock is undefined"*. Without the NiceMatrixBlock (only vNiceArrayC) I did not get the error.
   I use Texpad with pdflatex and MacTex.

Is there a better way to solve my issue (nicely aligned matrices with annotations) than nicematrix package?

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{gauss}

\begin{document}
gauss package
\begin{align*}
|A| &=  
\begin{gmatrix}[v]
0 & 0 & -5 & 4 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
-4 & -3 & -5 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & -1
\rowops
\swap{0}{3} 
\end{gmatrix}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot 
\begin{gmatrix}[v]
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\   
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
-4 & -3 & - 5 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 4
\rowops
\mult{2}{+ 4 \cdot \text{I}}
\end{gmatrix}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot
\begin{gmatrix}[v]
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & -5 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 4
\rowops
\mult{2}{+\text{II}}    
\end{gmatrix}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot
\begin{gmatrix}[v]
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 4
\rowops
\mult{3}{- \text{III}}  
\end{gmatrix}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot
\begin{gmatrix}[v]
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
\end{gmatrix}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot [1\cdot(-1)\cdot(-5)\cdot1]
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot 5
\\ \\
|A| &= -5
\end{align*}

\newpage
nicematrix package


\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
\begin{align*}
|A| & = 
\begin{vNiceArrayC}{CCCC}
0 & 0 & -5 & 4 & \text{change with IV}\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
-4 & -3 & -5 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & \text{change with I}
\end{vNiceArrayC}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot 
\begin{vNiceArrayC}{CCCC}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\   
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
-4 & -3 & - 5 & 3 & |+4\cdot \text{I}\\
0 & 0 & -5 & 4
\end{vNiceArrayC}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot
\begin{vNiceArrayC}{CCCC}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & -5 & -1 & |+\text{II}\\
0 & 0 & -5 & 4
\end{vNiceArrayC}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot
\begin{vNiceArrayC}{CCCC}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 4 & | - \text{III}
\end{vNiceArrayC}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot
\begin{vNiceArrayC}{CCCC}
1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
\end{vNiceArrayC}
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot [1\cdot(-1)\cdot(-5)\cdot1]
\\ \\
|A| &= (-1) \cdot 5
\\ \\
|A| &= -5
\end{align*}
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}


\end{document}
```

[image: gauss package]

[image: nicematrix package]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\begin{aligned}
|A| & =
    \begin{vNiceArrayC}{RRRR}[name=m]
     0 &  0 & -5 &  4 & \vphantom{X}    \\
     0 & -1 &  0 &  4                   \\
    -4 & -3 & -5 &  3                   \\
     1 &  1 &  0 & -1 & \vphantom{X}
    \end{vNiceArrayC}   \\
    & = (-1){\cdot}
    \begin{vNiceArrayC}{CCCC}[columns-width=1.5em] % <--- for comparison is C columns are select
     1 &  1 &  0 & -1 \\
     0 & -1 &  0 &  4 \\
    -4 & -3 & -5 &  3 & |+4{\cdot }\mathrm{I}\\
     0 &  0 & -5 &  4
    \end{vNiceArrayC}   \\
    & = (-1){\cdot}
    \begin{vNiceArrayC}{RRRR}[columns-width=1.5em]
    1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
    0 & 1 & -5 & -1 & |+\mathrm{II}\\
    0 & 0 & -5 & 4
    \end{vNiceArrayC}   \\
    & = (-1){\cdot}
    \begin{vNiceArrayC}{RRRR}[columns-width=1.5em]
    1 &  1 &  0 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 &  0 &  4 \\
    0 &  0 & -5 &  3 \\
    0 &  0 & -5 &  4 & | - \mathrm{III}
    \end{vNiceArrayC}   \\
    & = (-1){\cdot}
    \begin{vNiceArrayC}{RRRR}[columns-width=1.5em]
    1 &  1 &  0 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 &  0 &  4 \\
    0 &  0 & -5 &  3 \\
    0 &  0 &  0 &  1
    \end{vNiceArrayC}   \\
    & = (-1){\cdot} [1{\cdot}(-1){\cdot}(-5){\cdot}1]   \\
    & = (-1){\cdot}5    \\
|A| &= -5
\end{aligned}
\]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,name prefix =m-]
    \draw[<->] (1-5) -- ++ (4mm,0) |- (4-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

for comparison in `vNiceArrayC` i use `R` column specifier (except in second matrix). if you more prefer numbers centered in columns (as they are in the second matrix), just replace `R` with `C` in other matrices.

to obtain final looks of equations, you need to compile document (at least) twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This has solved my first question. I still have a problem to load nicematrix properly. I cannot define the columns width, neither on Texpad nor on Texshop. The error message says, that the "option is unknown". Texshop also clarifies that I request version "2018-10-17" of package sparse, but only "2018-02-21 L3 Experimental version" is available.

Comment: @Karl, my answer solve your both question what id concerning LaTeX, however, it seems that you have outdated `nicematrix` and `L3`. You need to update your installation, if you like to use `nicematrix`. in my recent `miktex` my solution works as shown in answer..

Comment: I updated my distribution and now your solution works perfectly as suggested. Thank you very much!