# Help with arrows and texts with a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, matrices

I want to typeset matrices with such arrows and maths as in the figure below. This one [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430441/matrices-with-arrows) is similar but not quite the same. Can someone give some pointers? Thanks.

[image: Figure]

Comment: Try with `nicematrix` package. Also improve quality of your sketch (make it more clear). As an (more complex) example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488685/alignment-of-matrices-with-annotations-on-the-right-side/.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Sorry for the sloppy figure.

Comment: Not sorry, please correct it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[
\raisebox{-.5pt}{$i^{\textup {th}}\, \textup{entry} \longrightarrow$}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
\vdots\\
 a_i\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
 \\
\longleftarrow j^{\textup {th}}\, \textup{entry}  \\
\\
\hspace{-1cm}\longrightarrow =0 \\
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @baharampuri You are welcome.